# How to get latest tag of git repository

Tags: javascript, git, simple-git

I'm using [simple-git](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git) and I need to get the commit hash of the latest tag.

So far I did it this way:

```
const tags: string = await git.tag({
    '--list': null,
    '--format': '%(objectname:short)'
})
const commitLastTag = tags.trim().split('\n').pop() || 'HEAD~1'
```

First it was working, but now there is a problem, which is caused by sorting. `tags` has the value (if not using --format):

```
v3.0.0
v3.0.1
v3.0.2
v3.0.3
v3.1.0
v3.10.0
v3.11.0
v3.2.0
v3.3.0
v3.4.0
v3.5.0
v3.5.1
v3.6.0
v3.6.1
v3.6.2
v3.6.3
v3.7.0
v3.7.1
v3.7.2
v3.8.0
v3.9.0
v3.9.1
v3.9.2
v3.9.3
```

As you can see now I do not get the latest tag - which should be v3.11.0

In the console I would do `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags` to get the latest tag, but there is no `describe` in simple-git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like `sort -V`, `git tag` has a similar option `--sort=version:refname` or `--sort=v:refname` to sort version numbers. It's a special instance of [--sort=<key>](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt---sortltkeygt).

If the version number is more complicated, the configuraion value [versionsort.suffix](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-versionsortsuffix) could help.

I'm not familiar with Javascript. But I guess its sort functions support a custome callback that determines the order of elements like `cmp` in the function `sorted(cmp=None, ...)` of Python. If it has such callbacks, I think you can sort any versions.